How to convert a .pth to a .pt?
How to convert a .pth (the formatting for the pre-trained voice library I’m using) to .pt (the formatting readable by the C# program im running it with)? I have only found information about torchvision (for converting .pth visual models).
There’s little documentation about PyTorch.audio, so I’m fairly lost.
(I am also aware that .pth and .pt are effectively the same, but python is interfering with the .pth formatting).
This was the closest I was able to get using the torchvision examples:
pth_file_path = 'FILE/PATH/model.pth' 
pt_file_path = 'FILE/PATH/model.pt'

import torch
import torchaudio
from unet import UNet
from zmq import device 
model = UNet(3, 2)

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(pth_file_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))

But it outputs a Runtime error:
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(pth_file_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\IMPORT.py", line 11, in <module>
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(pth_file_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 2215, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for UNet:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv1.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv1.block.0.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv2.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.0.conv2.block.0.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv1.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv1.block.0.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv2.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.1.conv2.block.0.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv1.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv1.block.0.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv2.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.2.conv2.block.0.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv1.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv1.block.0.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv2.block.0.weight", "encoder.encoding_blocks.3.conv2.block.0.bias", "bottom_block.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "bottom_block.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "bottom_block.conv1.block.0.weight", "bottom_block.conv1.block.0.bias", "bottom_block.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "bottom_block.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "bottom_block.conv2.block.0.weight", "bottom_block.conv2.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.upsample.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.upsample.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv1.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv1.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv2.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.0.conv2.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.upsample.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.upsample.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv1.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv1.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv2.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.1.conv2.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.upsample.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.upsample.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv1.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv1.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv2.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.2.conv2.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.upsample.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.upsample.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv1.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv1.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv1.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv1.block.0.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv2.conv_layer.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv2.conv_layer.bias", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv2.block.0.weight", "decoder.decoding_blocks.3.conv2.block.0.bias", "classifier.conv_layer.weight", "classifier.conv_layer.bias", "classifier.block.0.weight", "classifier.block.0.bias".
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "weight", "config", "info", "sr", "f0", "version".


Where and how do you want to run the model? Which model specifically?

Unfortunately I don't have recent relevant experience with C# to provide a helpful answer, however I hope a few pointers could help. I was tempted to point to torch.jit.script (or torch.jit.trace) to "freeze" a model for inference. When I searched for C# torch inference I noticed a lot of results pointing to optimising/exporting to ONNX format. TorchSharp looks interesting. Might be worth a try...

...hopefully the audio part is support enough for your application/(UNet model) or at least the ability to use torch script to export your model from pytorch to .pth to use in TorchSharp.(If the layer types in your model aren't supported CreatingYourOwnTorchSharpModules could help. Going over Python torch.jit documentation will help. A scripted/traced model is not the same as the original model.
